# how to replace a substring using pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file which has some data like this:

```
- data: {text: '=', name: '10', id: 316, row: 8, column: 1, width: 19, height: 1}
```

I want to replace the `'='` with `=` and `'10'` with `10`.

I have tried using

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("\\w+:\\s\\'(.*)\\'"); 
matcher.group(1);
```

This gives me `=', name: '10`

But I need to get `=`.

How do I find all the matches?

Answer (score 3):

> `I want to replace the '=' with = and '10' with 10`

You can probably do:

```
data = data.replaceAll("'([^']*)'", "$1");
```

to string all strings from single quote.

`OR make it more restrictive by replacing only 10 OR = only:`

```
data = data.replaceAll("'(10|=)'", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is RegEx *really* required here? If all you're trying to do is just replace those 2, perhaps you should try something like:

```
string = string.replace("'", "");
```

I am assuming that you want to replace all of the values that are contained with in a `'`.

Or if you just want to replace only those 2 occurrences, feel free to try something like:

```
string = string.replace("'='", "=").replace("'10'", "10");
```

Comment: that helps but if i have text like say text: message to 'Josh' then this should not be replaced

Comment: @Raghav Then the latter solution (`string = string.replace("'='", "=").replace("'10'", "10");`) is definitely what you are looking for.

Comment: its a text file i am using and we are not sure what data come in and the file ranges around 7 to 8 mb

Comment: @JoshM you could enforce escape sequences in the strings that contain a `'`. It's what has been done for a while and is probably preferred due to the simplicity of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for thing you need it is very very simple :

```
    String change = "text: '=', name: '10', id: 316, row: 8, column: 1, width: 19, height: 1";
    String newString = change.replaceAll("'", "");
```

Comment: that helps but if i have text like say text: message to 'libik' then this should not be replaced